# Trying to use unity JsonUtility to serialize a multidimentional array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to save a generic multidimensional array as json (this is not the main functionality, just the end goal) I want to keep the original location in the multidimensional array, so I can parse it back.

here's my code:

```
[Serializable]
public class Serializable2DArray<T>
{
    public Serializable2DObject<T>[] data;

    public Serializable2DArray(T[,] t)
    {
        List<Serializable2DObject<T>> tt = new List<Serializable2DObject<T>>();
        for (int x = 0; x < t.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < t.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                Serializable2DObject<T> td = new Serializable2DObject<T>(t[x, y], x, y);
                tt.Add(td);
            }
        }
        data = tt.ToArray();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Serializable2DObject<T>
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public T obj;

    public Serializable2DObject(T d, int _x, int _y)
    {
        obj = d;
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your assistance!

Edit:
I have this on the other end actually using the functions:

```
Serializable2DArray<TileData> md = new Serializable2DArray<TileData>(Mapdata);
string a = JsonUtility.ToJson(md, true);
File.WriteAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/map.json", a);
```

Tiledata Class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class TileData
{
    public int tileNumber;
    public Vector3 position;
    public int toughness;
    public int health;
}
```

this all is returning "{ }"
and I want it to return the proper array of objects

Sorry if my question was unclear.

Comment: It is not clear what your question is and/or what is causing a problem.

Comment: I added some more information, is it more clear now?

Comment: You can't serialize generic type in Unity. A quick Google search will give you the solution. Basically, you need to have an inheriting class from the generic type. https://answers.unity.com/questions/1498690/jsonutilityfromjson-to-a-class-with-generic-type.html